# How do I define the __str__ method for a foreignkey field in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

How do I define the **str** method for a foreignkey field in Django? The code below does not work,

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey('B')

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

Comment: `does not work` is the vaguest description of a question. What doesn't work? What's the expected outcome? What's the actual outcome?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If your model `B` has a `name` field, you could:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.name.name
```

Or you could try define the `__str__` method in `B` model.

Comment: If the attribute you're wanting to refer to is the primary key then it would be more efficient to use return self.name_id

Answer (score 7):

Table 'A' has a Foreign Key of Table 'B', You can Define like this:

```
class B(models.Model):
    something=models.CharField(max_length=50)

class A(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey('B')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name.something
```

Comment: I am still having error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute something. Could you advise?

Answer (score 2):

@Gocht has the correct answer, the code at the moment is basically calling the **str** method of your Model B, which is presumably unset.

You can reference foreign key fields in the STR box, but unless you also set list_display on the ModelAdmin for Model A I'd not reccomend it if you need a responsive admin module.

You will end up with literally thousands of queries for each page load. Any bulk deletion task will become a vision of eggtimers..