# __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType) because the field is null

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm getting this error in my model PedidoPizzaThrough:

```
__str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)
```

I assume it's maybe because the fields are null for now but I added the else "" and nothing changes. How do I fix this?

My model is like this:

```
class Pizzas(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    cant = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre


class Pedido(models.Model):
    fecha = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=200, null=True)
    telefono = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    pizzas = models.ManyToManyField('Pizzas', through='PedidoPizzaThrough', related_name='pedidos')
    cantidad = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
    
class PedidoPizzaThrough(models.Model):
    pizza = models.ForeignKey(Pizzas, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    pedido = models.ForeignKey(Pedido, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    cantidad = models.IntegerField()
    

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.pizza) if str(self.pizza) else ""
```

This is the traceback:

```
django-challenge-back | Traceback (most recent call last):
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
django-challenge-back |     response = get_response(request)
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 204, in _get_response
django-challenge-back |     response = response.render()
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 105, in render
django-challenge-back |     self.content = self.rendered_content
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/response.py", line 70, in rendered_content
django-challenge-back |     ret = renderer.render(self.data, accepted_media_type, context)
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 724, in render
django-challenge-back |     context = self.get_context(data, accepted_media_type, renderer_context)
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 696, in get_context
django-challenge-back |     'post_form': self.get_rendered_html_form(data, view, 'POST', request),
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 511, in get_rendered_html_form
django-challenge-back |     return self.render_form_for_serializer(serializer)
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 518, in render_form_for_serializer
django-challenge-back |     return form_renderer.render(
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 372, in render
django-challenge-back |     return template.render(context)
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
django-challenge-back |     return self.template.render(context)
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 170, in render
django-challenge-back |     return self._render(context)
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 162, in _render
django-challenge-back |     return self.nodelist.render(context)
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
django-challenge-back |     bit = node.render_annotated(context)
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
django-challenge-back |     return self.render(context)
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 211, in render
django-challenge-back |     nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
django-challenge-back |     return self.render(context)
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 312, in render
django-challenge-back |     return nodelist.render(context)
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
django-challenge-back |     bit = node.render_annotated(context)
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
django-challenge-back |     return self.render(context)
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/library.py", line 192, in render
django-challenge-back |     output = self.func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs)
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/templatetags/rest_framework.py", line 87, in render_field
django-challenge-back |     return renderer.render_field(field, style)
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 351, in render_field
django-challenge-back |     return template.render(context)
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
django-challenge-back |     return self.template.render(context)
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 170, in render
django-challenge-back |     return self._render(context)
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 162, in _render
django-challenge-back |     return self.nodelist.render(context)
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
django-challenge-back |     bit = node.render_annotated(context)
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
django-challenge-back |     return self.render(context)
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 163, in render
django-challenge-back |     values = self.sequence.resolve(context, ignore_failures=True)
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 671, in resolve
django-challenge-back |     obj = self.var.resolve(context)
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 796, in resolve
django-challenge-back |     value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 858, in _resolve_lookup
django-challenge-back |     current = current()
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/relations.py", line 220, in iter_options
django-challenge-back |     self.get_choices(cutoff=self.html_cutoff),
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/relations.py", line 202, in get_choices
django-challenge-back |     return OrderedDict([
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/relations.py", line 205, in <listcomp>
django-challenge-back |     self.display_value(item)
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/relations.py", line 226, in display_value
django-challenge-back |     return str(instance)
django-challenge-back | TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)
django-challenge-back | [18/Apr/2021 23:51:17] "GET /pizzadelmes HTTP/1.1" 500 220029
django-challenge-back | Internal Server Error: /pizzadelmes
django-challenge-back | Traceback (most recent call last):
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
django-challenge-back |     response = get_response(request)
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 204, in _get_response
django-challenge-back |     response = response.render()
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 105, in render
django-challenge-back |     self.content = self.rendered_content
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/response.py", line 70, in rendered_content
django-challenge-back |     ret = renderer.render(self.data, accepted_media_type, context)
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 724, in render
django-challenge-back |     context = self.get_context(data, accepted_media_type, renderer_context)
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 696, in get_context
django-challenge-back |     'post_form': self.get_rendered_html_form(data, view, 'POST', request),
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 511, in get_rendered_html_form
django-challenge-back |     return self.render_form_for_serializer(serializer)
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 518, in render_form_for_serializer
django-challenge-back |     return form_renderer.render(
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 372, in render
django-challenge-back |     return template.render(context)
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
django-challenge-back |     return self.template.render(context)
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 170, in render
django-challenge-back |     return self._render(context)
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 162, in _render
django-challenge-back |     return self.nodelist.render(context)
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
django-challenge-back |     bit = node.render_annotated(context)
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
django-challenge-back |     return self.render(context)
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 211, in render
django-challenge-back |     nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
django-challenge-back |     return self.render(context)
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 312, in render
django-challenge-back |     return nodelist.render(context)
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
django-challenge-back |     bit = node.render_annotated(context)
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
django-challenge-back |     return self.render(context)
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/library.py", line 192, in render
django-challenge-back |     output = self.func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs)
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/templatetags/rest_framework.py", line 87, in render_field
django-challenge-back |     return renderer.render_field(field, style)
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 351, in render_field
django-challenge-back |     return template.render(context)
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
django-challenge-back |     return self.template.render(context)
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 170, in render
django-challenge-back |     return self._render(context)
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 162, in _render
django-challenge-back |     return self.nodelist.render(context)
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
django-challenge-back |     bit = node.render_annotated(context)
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
django-challenge-back |     return self.render(context)
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 163, in render
django-challenge-back |     values = self.sequence.resolve(context, ignore_failures=True)
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 671, in resolve
django-challenge-back |     obj = self.var.resolve(context)
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 796, in resolve
django-challenge-back |     value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 858, in _resolve_lookup
django-challenge-back |     current = current()
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/relations.py", line 220, in iter_options
django-challenge-back |     self.get_choices(cutoff=self.html_cutoff),
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/relations.py", line 202, in get_choices
django-challenge-back |     return OrderedDict([
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/relations.py", line 205, in <listcomp>
django-challenge-back |     self.display_value(item)
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/relations.py", line 226, in display_value
django-challenge-back |     return str(instance)
django-challenge-back | TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I define the \_\_str\_\_ method for a foreignkey field in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38776283/how-do-i-define-the-str-method-for-a-foreignkey-field-in-django)

Comment: @HenryEcker I've tried that but it doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: `Pedido.email` is nullable and is used for the `__str__` method, you may need to handle it being null

Comment: @IainShelvington But I am trying to return pizza fields which are not nullable and even there I've put an else "", wouldn't that be enough technically?

Comment: Can you post the full traceback?

Comment: @IainShelvington I added it.

Comment: How do you know the problem is with `PedidoPizzaThrough`, and not one of the other models?

Comment: @JohnGordon Ah, you were right, that was the issue, it was somewhere else. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not immediately obvious, but here's a few suggestions.

Try this for `PedidoPizzaThrough`'s `__str__` method

```py
def __str__(self):
    if not self.pizza:
        return ""
    return str(self.pizza)
```

Some thoughts:

- `email` is a nullable field on `Pedido`. If you try to `str` an instance of this mode, you could get this error.
- Is it possible you have data that made its way into the DB without django? If `nombre` is null, it's possible that when you try to `str` the `pizza` attribute, it will access `Pizzas`'s `__str__` method and return a `None`, so it never gets to actually use your ternary, meaining `str(self.pizza)` itself is throwing the error.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I did try this but it doesn't seem to change anything, even though nombre is not null..

Comment: Could it be the `__str__` method of `Pedido` then? Did you try doing the equivalent of my suggestion for that model?

Comment: yes, in the end the error was somewhere else. Thank you for the help!