# AttributeError Exception Value: 'IntegerField' object has no attribute 'max_length'

Tags: python, django

I did not put any max_length restrictions on the IntegerField hence I am not sure what is the issue.
The code below is in models.py. Please tell me what else do i need to provide to give a better understanding to this issue.

Django version: Django==3.2

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Technology(models.Model):
id = models.IntegerField(db_column='id', primary_key = True)
name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
node = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)

   def __str__(self):
      return self.name

   class Meta:
    
      db_table = 'technology'
      unique_together = (('name','node'),)

class Metalstack(models.Model):
id = models.IntegerField(db_column='id', primary_key = True)
techname = models.ForeignKey('Technology', to_field = 'name', on_delete = models.CASCADE, db_column ="techname",blank=True, null=True)
stackname = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True, db_column ="stackname")

  def __str__(self):
      return self.stackname

  class Meta:
  
      db_table = 'metalstack'
      unique_together = (('techname', 'stackname'),)

class Thickness(models.Model):
id = models.IntegerField(db_column='id', primary_key = True)
stack_id = models.ForeignKey(Metalstack, to_field = 'id', on_delete = models.CASCADE, db_column ="stack_id",blank=True, null=True )
thickness = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2,blank=True, null=True)

  class Meta:
   
      db_table = 'thickness'
      unique_together = (('stack_id', 'thickness'),)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please post the full traceback error.

Comment: hi sorry, i dont know what is the best way to post a long text but hope this helps, https://dpaste.com/EQ76SG385

Comment: Can you also include the website template that is related to the url you're trying to access? ie. the code that responds to ```admin/website/thickness/1/change/```

Comment: error displayed: https://dpaste.com/DE72XTSPK. It is actually a table in my exisiting database (MYSQL) that i was syncing with django via syncdb. And when i try to access the rows in the different table from the admin page, that error came up.

Answer (score 0):

Integer fields don't have `max_length` property, you can achieve that with 3 methods:

1. Using a [MaxValueValidator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/validators/#maxvaluevalidator)
2. Changing `id` to `CharField`
3. Force the validation in the forms

Comment: thank you i will give that a try. Why will that error occur even though i did not set any max_length properties?

Comment: hi changing to charfield did not work. and i am not able to set a max value as i want to make this scalable with reference to an existing database

Answer (score 0):

The issue was at how I display my thickness model in the models.py file. Initially, I did not even add any def **str** so I thought that was the issue. So, I then tried to follow [stackoverflow resource for multiple displays across model class, foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38776283/how-do-i-define-the-str-method-for-a-foreignkey-field-in-django)

This did not work and gave a new error of the class not exisitng:

```
class Thickness(models.Model):
id = models.TextField(db_column='id', primary_key = True)
stack_id = models.ForeignKey(Metalstack, to_field = 'id', on_delete = models.CASCADE, db_column ="stack_id",blank=True, null=True )
thickness = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2,blank=True, null=True)

def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.stack_id} {self.Metalstack.id}'
```

But when I changed it into this it worked without errors, not even the intial max_length error.

```
class Thickness(models.Model):
id = models.TextField(db_column='id', primary_key = True)
stack_id = models.ForeignKey(Metalstack, to_field = 'id', on_delete = models.CASCADE, db_column ="stack_id",blank=True, null=True )
thickness = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2,blank=True, null=True)

def __str__(self):

        return '%s %s' % (str(self.stack_id), self.stack_id.id )
```

I am not sure how it solved the initial error but hope this might help someone.